# RegEx pattern to extract URLs

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have to extract all there is between this caracters:

```
<a href="/url?q=(text to extract whatever it is)&amp
```

I tried this pattern, but it's not working for me:

```
/(?<=url\?q=).*?(?=&amp)/
```

I'm programming in Vb.net, this is the code, but I think that the problem is that the pattern is wrong:

```
    Dim matches As MatchCollection

    matches = regex.Matches(TextBox1.Text)

    For Each Match As Match In matches

        listbox1.items.add(Match.Value)

    Next
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: I tested your regex at http://rubular.com/ and it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is seemed to be correct except the slash(`/`) in the beginning and ending of expression, remove it:

```
Dim regex = New Regex("(?<=url\?q=).*?(?=&amp)")
```

and it should work.

Some utilities and most languages use `/` (forward slash) to start and end (de-limit or contain) the search expression others may use single quotes. With `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` you don't need it.

Comment: I love you! XD i used slash because i read that it need for start and the end of the pattern... but maybe i was wrong...

Answer (score 0):

This regex code below will extract all urls from your text (or any other):

`(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?`